# Django. Фильтрация и сортировка по свойству (не по полю) модели

Tags: python, django

Есть классы: **Соревнование**, **Гимнаст**.
Класс **Гимнаст** имеет ForeignKey для класса **Соревнование**.
Так же в классе **Гимнаст** есть метод для вычисления позиции в рейтинге. Если **Гимнаст** ещё не выступал, то позиция не определена (None).
Как вывести список гимнастов имеющих рейтинг (rank) отличный от None и отсортированный по возрастанию?

```
class Competition(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

class Gymnast(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Competition, related_name='gymnasts')
    name = models.CharField()

    def calc_rank(self):
        // вычисляется позиция в рейтинге
        if rank:
            return rank
        return None
    calc_rank.short_description = "место в зачёте"
    rank = property(calc_rank)
```

Если пытаюсь вывести с фильтрацией:

```
{% for gymnast in competition.gymnasts.all|rank %}
```

то получаю ошибку: "Invalid filter: 'rank_position'".
Если пытаюсь вывести с сортировкой:

```
{% for gymnast in competition.gymnasts.all|dictsort:"rank" %}
```

то ничего не выводится...

Comment: А зачем запрос делать в шаблоне? Не лучше ли сделать его во вьюхе? Логика всё-таки должна быть в отображениях.

Comment: Наверное лучше во вьюхе, но до них ещё не дошёл... Не подскажите как это лучше реализовать? Может пример похожий есть?

Answer (score 1):

Один из способов решения, как мне кажется, более простой.

Метод ранг, нужно сделать полем модели, и вычислять позицию в рейтинге, классом Соревнование, которое знает обо всех участниках, ведь я так понимаю позиция в рейтинге одного из участников зависит так же и от успехов остальных, и прописывать эту позицию уже в поле.

Запрос же будет выглядеть тогда так:

```
Gymtast.objects.all().exclude(rank=None).order_by("-rank")

order_by("-rank") # это сортировка в обратном порядке
exclude(rank=None) # это исключить записи с rank == None
```

Comment: А на сколько это, так сказать, идейно правильно - делать полем подобную штуку? Ведь если участников много, скажем 50-100, то каждый раз надо перезаписывать поля "rank" всех участников в базе данных. Или это не такая большая проблема?

Comment: Сотня записей моментально перезаписывается. Проблемой бы было если бы записей был миллион, но рейтинг обычно не вычисляется динамически, обычно он отображается очками, как рейтинг "Эло".  В случае с рейтингом по "Эло", это было бы такое же отдельное поле в таблице с набранными участником очками.